# css3 framework for ie7

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7

I would like to know what you guys use when you need to use css3 features in IE7. Some frontend-developer told me that "CSS pie" was the way to go. It will mostly be used for rounded corners and shadows.

Should i get some kind of css3 framework, or get a separate "fix" for each of the css3 properties?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PIE not only support rounded corners and shadows
here is full list of features

http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

Here is Comparing PIE to Other CSS3 Products

http://css3pie.com/documentation/product-comparison/

Comment: maybe it cause problem when applied to a dropdown menu and other elements at the same time

Comment: yes
i avoid using it when i need drop down shadows
and round corners for dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

I've had some luck with [IE-CSS3](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/%20IE-CSS3) in the past, but mostly for a select few features.